# Adjective or verb

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Is: The girl looked angrily to us 
Or
The girl looked angry to us 
Which one is true? I think say that the second one to me is true but i have been told that the first one is true
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid sentences, but they mean different things:

- "The girl looked angrily to us": *angrily* modifies the verb *looked*. In other words, the girl looked in your direction, and something about the way in which she did so suggested anger on her part.
- "The girl looked angry to us": *angry* modifies the noun *girl*. You've come to the conclusion based on her appearance that she's angry, but you're not describing any action that she's taken.

Also note that *angrily* is an adverb and *angry* is an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The girl looked angrily *at* us = she *looked* at us *with anger* (or *angrily*, adv.)

The girl looked angry to us = she *seemed* to be angry (adj.)

Comment: I don't think there's a need to change _to_ to _at_ in the first sentence. Consider _to_ as a poetic short form of _towards_.

Comment: Yes, it's possible (like 'looking **to** the left' or towards somebody else), but when a look is given in your direction, the natural feeling is they look _at_ you (_us_ here) not just direct their look towards you.